# Unable to show data from database in Laravel after inserting data into database

Tags: laravel

I was able to insert data into database in Laravel but when I was trying to show the data in a tabular form I couldn't - it was displaying `Route [stock_edit] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views\dashboard\stock-show.blade.php)`

Like I said in my quetion yesterday, I am new to Laravel and I am yet to understand the environment. I have been on this for the past 48 hours searching for help online but couldn't find a satisfactory ones

Here is my stock-show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('title', 'All Stock')
@section('content')


    @if(count($stock))

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">


                <div class="portlet light bordered">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption font-dark">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tools"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">

                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID#</th>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($stock as $p)
                                <tr>

                                    <td>{{ $p->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $p->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $p->price }} </td>
                                    <td>

                                        <a href="{{ route('stock_edit',$p->id) }}" class="btn purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> EDIT</a>

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_button"
                                                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DelModal"
                                                data-id="{{ $p->id }}">
                                            <i class='fa fa-times'></i> DELETE
                                        </button>

                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            @endforeach

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div><!-- ROW-->


        <div class="text-center">
            {!! $stock->render() !!}
        </div>
    @else

        <div class="text-center">
            <h3>No Data available</h3>
        </div>
        @endif

                <!-- Modal for DELETE -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="DelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> <i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete !</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <strong>Are you sure you want to Delete ?</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <form method="post" action="{{ route('stock_delete') }}" class="form-inline">
                            {!! csrf_field() !!}
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" class="abir_id" value="0">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on("click", '.delete_button', function (e) {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                $(".abir_id").val(id);

            });

        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

and this is the DashboardController.php

```
//Stocks
    public function createStock()
    {
        $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
        $data['page_title'] = "Create Stock";
        //$data['currency'] = Currency::all();
        return view('dashboard.stock-create',$data);
    }
    public function storeStock(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
           'name' => 'required|unique:stocks,name',
            'price' => 'required',
            //'currency_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        try {
            $stock = Input::except('_method','_token');
            Stock::create($stock);
            session()->flash('message', 'Stock Create Successfully.');
            Session::flash('type', 'success');
            return redirect()->back();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            session()->flash('message', 'Some Problem Occurs, Please Try Again!');
            Session::flash('type', 'danger');
            return redirect()->back();
        }


    }
    public function showStock()
    {
        $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
        $data['page_title'] = "All Stock";
        $data['stock'] = Stock::orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(100);
        return view('dashboard.stock-show',$data);
    }
    public function editStock($id)
    {
        $data['stock'] = Stock::findOrFail($id);
        $data['site_title'] = $this->site_title;
        $data['page_title'] = 'Edit Product';
        $data['stock'] = Stock::all();
        return view('dashboard.stock-edit',$data);
    }
    public function updateStock(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $stocks = Stock::findOrFail($id);
        $this->validate($request,[
           'name' => 'required|unique:stocks,name,'.$stocks->id,
            'price' => 'required',
            //'currency_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        try {
            $stock = Input::except('_method','_token');
            $stocks->fill($stock)->save();
            session()->flash('message', 'Stock Updated Successfully.');
            Session::flash('type', 'success');
            return redirect()->back();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            session()->flash('message', 'Some Problem Occurs, Please Try Again!');
            Session::flash('type', 'danger');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }//Stocks End
```

And lastly the route.php

```
/* Stock Route List */
Route::get('stock-create',['as'=>'stock-create','uses'=>'DashboardController@createStock']);
Route::post('stock-create',['as'=>'stock-store','uses'=>'DashboardController@storeStock']);
Route::get('stock-show',['as'=>'stock-show','uses'=>'DashboardController@showStock']);
Route::get('stock-edit/{id}',['as'=>'stock-edit','uses'=>'DashboardController@editStock']);
Route::put('stock-edit/{id}',['as'=>'stock-update','uses'=>'DashboardController@updateStock']);
```

Comment: You have taken `href="{{ route('stock_edit',$p->id) }}"` in your `stock` blade file but not in route.php file.

Comment: Change `Route::put('stock-edit/{id}',['as'=>'stock-update','uses'=>'DashboardController@updateStock']);
` to `Route::put('stock_edit/{id}',['as'=>'stock-update','uses'=>'DashboardController@updateStock']);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code,

change `stock_edit` to `stock-edit` in your view

Comment: Thanks guys. Working now.